# ExpandableListview with and without child android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

I am using NavingationalDrawer from [sliding-menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

And using ExpandableLisview from [ExpandableLisview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

I customized NavingationalDrawer to Expandable listview.

My Expandable listview contains List items with and without child

When on click on item with child ,it expands , as expected , but the items get repeated due to For loop

When on click on item without child ,it crashes, as not expected

```
private class GetCatList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            //expListView.setVisibility(8);
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()) == true) {
                 //navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

                // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(All_link.CATEGORY_URL,
                        ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        cat = jsonObj.getJSONArray(All_link.TAG_NEWS);

                        String err = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_ERROR);
                        Log.e("------>Error", String.valueOf(err));

                        if (err.equals("1")) {

                        } else {

                            // looping through All Contacts
                            for (int i = 0; i < cat.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = cat.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = c.getString(All_link.TAG_CAT_ID);
                                String cat_name = c
                                        .getString(All_link.TAG_CAT_NAME);
                                String image_icon = c.getString("image_icon");

                                /*navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(cat_name,
                                        image_icon, navMenuIcons.getResourceId(
                                                1, -1), true
                                                ,"1",id));*/

                                listDataHeader.add("News Category");
                                list_items.add(cat_name);                                                                                           
                                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), list_items);
                                Log.e("list_items", "karlist "+list_items);
                            }
                            listDataHeader.add("News Today");



                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler",
                            "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Network Error", "Internet Connection Error");
                error_flag = 1;
                // error = "Internet Connection Error";

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (error_flag == 1) {

                expListView.setVisibility(8);
                // main_error.setText("Internet Connection Error! Please check your network settings and try again");
                // main_error.setVisibility(0);

            } else {

                /*
                 * navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1],
                 * navMenuIcons .getResourceId(0, -1),"1"));
                 */

                expListView.setVisibility(0);
                // main_error.setText("");
                // main_error.setVisibility(8);

                // Recycle the typed array
                navMenuIcons.recycle();

                expListView
                        .setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

                // setting the nav drawer list adapter
                /*adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        navDrawerItems);*/
                listAdapter=new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                expListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
                expListView.setSelection(0);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only one remark: `listDataHeader.add("News Category");`. You do that `cat.length()` times. So you will see that group so often. Please explain. `list_items`. Please show type and definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I solved my issue..  by the help of [this link](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html)